# Creating a Dynamic Kernel Dispatcher in C++

Tags: c++, architecture, software-design

I have multiple implementations for the same function, one SIMD Accelerated, One a Cuda kernel, and another one in SYCL. The user can choose which kernel to use using an int parameter, 0 for Vanilla, 1 for SIMD, 2 for a Cuda kernel, and 3 for SYCL. The pseudocode is as follows(I am using C++) -

```
return type function(param1, param2, int device){
switch(device):
    case Vanilla:
        Normal Code.(Written right over here)
    case SIMD:
        Calls the SIMD Kernel
    case Nvidia :
        Calls the Cuda Kernel
    case SYCL :
        Calls the SYCL kernel
}
```

All the kernels are present in a separate folder named Kernels with subfolders as SIMD, Cuda, and SYCL. Now, one cannot expect a user to have Cuda but can run SYCL (Has an AMD GPU) and so on and so forth. So using a cmake option, these folders are conditionally compiled as specified by the user. The end goal is to create a library that can be installed by the user.

So I do not want to include the files which contain these kernels but rather create a dynamic dispatcher intermediate.
How can I get started designing the same? 
TIA

Comment: It's not the solution you are looking for, but you could use the same technique as the BabelStream benchmark project https://github.com/UoB-HPC/BabelStream. See https://github.com/UoB-HPC/BabelStream/blob/main/main.cpp#L237 where the different kernels are set up.

Comment: Thanks you for replying @RodBurns, I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, But I figured during the installation process I could write a file called `installation.h` which could be as follows -

```
#define __SIMD_x86_64__ 1
#define __CUDA__ 1
#define __SYCL__ 1
#define __SIMD_ARM_NEON__ 0
```

The dispatcher can conditionally include headers from various folders which contain the kernels for the various device backend. Then a dispatcher could be made using a branch table, using a dispatcher key according to ti the function.

```
#include "installation.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map <std::string, function_pointer> branch_table;

#if defined(__SIMD_x86_64__)
    include "SIMD Kernels"
    Add Kernels to the Map;
#endif

#if defined(__CUDA__)
    include "CUDA Kernels"
    Add them to the Map;
#endif
```

And So on and so forth. I haven't tested this yet and might not be the best solution. But it looks like it works.

Thanks a lot to @rodburns for the guidance.